# Filter terms query don't work - Elasticseach and the java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm new to stackoverflow

here is my problem

I want to make a request in ES that in first perform a **must** then a **filter**. In sql it should lookalike to this below

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "the_name" AND type IN ("type1", "type2")
```

Here is my implementation of this case

```
@Override
public List<Example> findByName(String pattern, String... types) {
    // Prepare query
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", pattern))
            .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("type", types));

    // Execute query    
    return new ArrayList<>(this.elasticsearchQuery.findAgainstFields(Example.class, queryBuilder));
}
```

Next, my implementation for method **findAgainstFields**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> List<T> findAgainstFields(Class<?> t, QueryBuilder query) {
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();

    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder
            .withIndices("my_indice")
            .withTypes(t.getSimpleName())
            .withSort(new ScoreSortBuilder().order(SortOrder.DESC))
            .withQuery(query)
            .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 5)).build();

    // Execute query
    return (List<T>) this.elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, t);
}
```

And when I run the project this method (**findByName**) return an empty array. However, when I remove the `.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("type", types))` i got a result. So, on which part i'm wrong?

Thanks in advance

ps: I use ES 5.5 and Java 8 oracle

**UPDATE**

ES query is this:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "name" : {
            "value" : "eso",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "type" : [
            "Society",
            "Institut"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "disable_coord" : false,
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

So here, i try to find the data with **name** as **eso** with **type** who can be **Society** or **Institut**

Comment: could you post raw ES query?

Comment: Have you checked the casing of the values of `types`, i.e. whether they correspond to what you have in your documents?

Comment: yes, i've checked this point

Comment: ok, i finally found a solution. i've change the type of the property **type** to **keyword** (it was _text_ befor) in the mapping file and everything works fine. i don't understand this behavior. so to conclude, it's was not a problem on the java code but the mapping

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the mapping file not on java source code.
so i updated the file by changing the type of the property **type** to **keyword** (it was *text* before) and everything works fine.