# Elastic termsQuery not giving expected result

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have an index where each of my objects has `status` field which can have some predefined values. I want to fetch all of them which has status`INITIATED`, `UPDATED`, `DELETED`, any match with these and hence created this query by java which I got printing on console, using Querybuilder and nativeSearchQuery, executing by `ElasticsearchOperations`:

```
 {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "status" : [
            "INITIATED",
            "UPDATED",
            "DELETED"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

I have data in my index with 'INITIATED' status but not getting anyone with status mentioned in the query. How to fix this query, please?
If you need anything, please let me know.

**Update: code added**

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder=new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
QueryBuildersingleQb=QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("status",statusList));
                                        
  Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Defs.START_TIME).ascending());
                FieldSortBuilder sort = SortBuilders.fieldSort(Defs.START_TIME).order(SortOrder.ASC); 
  nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(singleQb);
  nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withSort(sort);
  nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withPageable(pageable);
                nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(Defs.SCHEDULED_MEETING_INDEX);
                nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withTypes(Defs.SCHEDULED_MEETING_INDEX);
    
 NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
 List<ScheduledMeetingEntity> scheduledList=elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, ScheduledMeetingEntity.class);
```

**Update 2: sample data:**

```
I got this from kibana query on this index:
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "type_name",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createTime" : "2021-03-03T13:09:59.198",
          "createTimeInMs" : 1614755399198,
          "createdBy" : "user1@domain.com",
          "editTime" : "2021-03-03T13:09:59.198",
          "editTimeInMs" : 1614755399198,
          "editedBy" : "user1@domain.com",
          "versionId" : 1,
          "id" : "1",
          "meetingId" : "47",
          "userId" : "129",
          "username" : "user1@domain.com",
          "recipient" : [
            "user1@domain.com"
          ],
          "subject" : "subject",
          "body" : "hi there",
          "startTime" : "2021-03-04T07:26:00.000",
          "endTime" : "2021-03-04T07:30:00.000",
          "meetingName" : "name123",
          "meetingPlace" : "placeName",
          "description" : "sfsafsdafsdf",
          "projectName" : "",
          "status" : "INITIATED",
          "failTry" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of a document for your index?

Comment: @SusanMustafa, please check now, data added

Comment: Try to do a simple termsQuery, with only INITIATED and see if you get results?
Try to do it without Pagination and see if you get results?

It might be your mapping as well.  Is it of type keyword?? or is it text?? for field Status?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739370/filter-terms-query-dont-work-elasticseach-and-the-java-api

TermsQuery needs to work with keyword.  I suggest you dont do your own mapping, but let ES do it for you.  It will create the keyword and everything else (Pretty smart).

Comment: I didn't map the fields, es did when the program starts first. So, according to es, I guess they are in keyword field as this is a single valued field(though I didn;t explicitly declared as keyword). I get my desired output in this way for others but not this time, don't know why! Did you see any suspicious point in my query?

Comment: No sorry. Please see my suggestion of simplifying it (1 query), no pagingation and see if you get results.  Otherwise its the termsQuery that is wrong, or your mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm your mapping:

GET /yourIndexName/_mapping

And see if it is valid

Your mapping needs to have keyword for TermsQuery to work.

```
{
  "status": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES can automatically do the mapping for you (without you having to do it yourself) when you first push a document.  However you probably have finer control if you do the mapping yourself.

Either way, you need to have keyword defined for your status field.

=====================
Alternative Solution: (Case Insensitive)

If you have a Field named (status), and the values you want to search for are (INITIATED or UPDATED, or DELETED).

Then you can do it like this:

```
  BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(createStringSearchQuery());

public QueryBuilder createStringSearchQuery(){
            QueryStringQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(" INITIATED OR UPDATED OR DELETED ");
            queryBuilder.defaultField("status");

     return queryBuilder;


}
```

Printing the QueryBuilder:

```
{
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "INITIATED OR UPDATED OR DELETED",
      "default_field" : "status",
      "fields" : [ ],
      "type" : "best_fields",
      "default_operator" : "or",
      "max_determinized_states" : 10000,
      "enable_position_increments" : true,
      "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
      "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
      "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
      "phrase_slop" : 0,
      "escape" : false,
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the alternative solution. Btw, where is the problem with my query? I just want to know what the problem is. I have updated the question with my code, please check

Comment: thanks for pointing it out explicitly. I knew for single-valued string, they are keyword by default but learnt that they are not.  I declared them keyword and it works. +1 for the link/description